# Como obtener las claves de una columna con diccionarios?

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios, dataframe, pickle

Como obtener las claves de una columna con diccionarios?

Por ejemplo:

`df['topics]`:

```
0                  {'/Finance': 0.6600000262260437}
1                                                {}
2                                                {}
3    {'/Business & Industrial': 0.8700000047683716}
4                                                {}
3    {'/Business & Industrial': 0.8599000000000000}
```

Me gustaria obtener un diccionario como lo siguiente:

```
DIC = dict(
    'FINANCE' = 'Finance',
    'BUSINESS' = 'Business & Industrial'
)
```

Por lo momento hice:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
topics = list(set([str(d.keys()) for d in df['topics']]))
del df

TOPICS = { i : topics[i] for i in range(0, len(topics) ) }
```

Con la respuesta de [Lucas Damian](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/117155/lucas-damian):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
topics = list(set([str(d.keys()) for d in df['topics']]))

TOPICS={}
for row in df['topics']:
    for key,value in row.items():
        TOPICS[key] = key
del df

# remove duplicates
df = pd.DataFrame(TOPICS,index=range(len(TOPICS)))
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print(df.to_dict())
```

obtengo:

```
(base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\richmond2>python run.py
{'/Finance': {0: '/Finance'}, '/Business & Industrial': {0: '/Business & Industrial'}, ...
```

className='control_label')

No hay elementos duplicados hay diccionarios de nuevo ...

Comment: `for k,v in DIC.items():
    print(f'llave: {k}, valor: {v}')`
asi ? , igual fijate que seria `dict({'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'})`

Comment: @LucasDamian Ya no tengo `DIC`, me gustaria crearlo con `df['topics']`

Answer (score 0):

Sí lo tienes dentro de una `serie`. Puedes tratar de hacer algo como esto.

Hacer un bucle para iterar la serie y luego a cada elemento recorrerlo como un diccionario.

```
for row in df['topics']:
    for key,value in row.items():
        print(f'llave: {key}, valor: {value}')
```

Y si quiere crear un diccionario nuevo:

```
new_dict={}
for row in df['topics']:
    for key,value in row.items():
        new_dict[key] = value
```

donde `key` sería tu *clave*, y `value` el *valor* de cada *clave*

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Y como hacer para para evitar las llaves duplicadas?

Comment: por ejemplo si tienes la llave 'HOLA' y figura con dos valores distintos,x ej : HOLA:11 y HOLA:22 , quieres guardarlos de igual manera ?, porque esta solución solo estaría guardando la última coincidencia, o sea 'HOLA':22

Comment: No quiero guardar la valor. Solo las claves para hacer un diccionario del typo: `d= {'clave' : 'clave'}`

Comment: fijate si te deja hacer esto `df = pd.DataFrame(TOPICS,index=range(len(TOPICS)))` ; 
`df = df.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Gracias, pero ¿cómo puedo volver a hacer un diccionario después?

Comment: puedes hacer `df.to_dict()`  y te devolverá un diccionario